# How to set and get environment variables in CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I want to export some variable like environment name and access in the script executed using code deploy Amazon

Answer (score 2):

```
 if [ "$DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME" == "Staging" ]
  then
      Your command here
 fi
```

refrence
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/using-codedeploy-environment-variables/

Comment: The question is "how to set variable as DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME" ?